# Materializecss Datepicker Scrolls the page to top when click on it

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, materialize

I use [materializecss Datepicker](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html) in my web page and one worked fine until I add another datepicking option to my web page.

[image]

After that when I select a date background page scrolls to top automatically.

Place where I needed to load datepicker:

[image]

Place where I needed to load datepicker-1:

[image]

where the modal loads:

[image]

I this is my code for datepicker 1;

```
<div class="row dateRangeSelector orderStatusWidget-dateRangeSelector"
                                                     id="customDates">
   <div class="col s6 orderStatusWidgetDateWrapper">
            <label>From</label>
          <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="distStartDate">
</div>
<div class="col s6">
        <label>To</label>
        <input type="text" class="orderStatusWidget-datepicker"
                                                               id="endDate1">
</div>
```

datepicker 2:

```
<div class="row dateRangeSelector orderStatusWidget-dateRangeSelector" id="customDates">
       <div class="col s6 orderStatusWidgetDateWrapper">
           <label>From</label>
          <input type="text" class="datepicker orderStatusWidget-datepicker"
                                                           id="startDate">
        </div>
       <div class="col s6">
           <label>To</label>
           <input type="text" class="datepicker orderStatusWidget-datepicker"
                                                           id="endDate">
       </div>
  </div>
```

my javascript code:

```
$('#distStartDate').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: true, // Close upon selecting a date,
        onStart: function() {
            $('.picker').appendTo('body');
        }
    })
```

**same for each and every input.

After doing some element inceptions I figure out that picker element that needs to create near to element is created in bottom of the page in my case.

Please tell me a way to fix this error.